# Given a list of players, for each player, find a younger player to the left of him with the highest strength

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we have a list of players like below

```
Player format = {id, age, strength}

Input format = { player1, player2, ....}

Input : { {0, 14, 75}, {1, 17, 65}, {2, 17, 50}, {3, 13, 40}, {4, 16, 90}, {5, 17, 84}, {6, 16, 67} }
```

Given input as above, for each player find a younger player to left of him with highest strength and add this strength to the result else -1, For simplicity we can assume player ids same as index of the array

For the above input, output is

```
Output : { -1 , 75 , 75 , -1 , 75 , 90 , 75}
```

My approach is O(N^2):

```
int[] findStrengths() {
    int[][] players = new int[n][3];
    int[] res = new int[n];
    Arrays.fill(res, -1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
            if(players[j][1] < players[i][1]) {
                res[i] = Math.max(res[i], players[j][2]);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem in O(Nlog(N)) using some BST structure, or in O(N) using a monotonic stack / queue ?

Comment: Ideally you'd want a structure `S` such that the following algorithm is efficient: `for p in player_list: yield (q in S that is younger than p but maximises strength); if (exists q in S such that q.age <= p.age and q.strength >= p.strength): pass; elif (exists q in S such that p.age < q.age and p.strength > q.strength): remove q from S; add p to S; else: add p to S`. I think a **quadtree** could probably work for structure `S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach than the other one.

Create an ordered data structure mapping age to strength. For example an AVL tree. We will only keep the people who are stronger than anyone the same age or younger. It starts off empty. We can call it `best_strength`.

Let's assume it has methods to `add`, `delete`, `find_at_most` find (if any) the last entry that is at most a given age, and `find_next` one to find the first entry above that age.

The logic then goes like this.

```
create best_strength
create output
for player in players:
    (prev_age, prev_strength) = best_strength.find_at_most(player.age)
    if prev_strength is None or prev_strength < player.strength:
        output.append(-1)
        best_strength.add(age, player.strength)
        while True: # break loop inside
            (next_age, next_strength) = best_strength.find_next(player.age)
            if next_strength is None or player.strength < next_strength:
                best_strength.remove(next_age)
            else:
                break # exit loop here
    else:
        output.append(prev_strength)
```

This is `O(n log(n))` and you can use an existing ordered data structure.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in O(nlogn) by creating a self-balancing tree, e.g. modified AVL tree where you can insert players (the age will decide the position in the tree), but each node also stores the max strength in its subtree. It is possible to create such a tree and still being able to insert in O(logn). Easiest is to take an existing AVL tree implementation and modify it. If you have that you can just check from left to right and find max strength satisfying the age criteria by going down the tree which takes O(logn), afterwards insert player into tree and continue.

How to find max strength for age a (start with root node and initialize max = -1, fall back to -1 for non-existing values):

- If a < node.age: go left, if you can't return max
- If a > node.age: max = max(max, node.left.maxStrength, node.strength), go right, if you can't return max
- If a == node.age: return max(max, node.left.maxStrength)

In the case of equality instead of inserting the player afterwards you should only update the strength if it is greater and then propagate it to update parent maxStrength values where needed.

Comment: I got the point, but the sub-tree can contain an age value more than the current node, For example, [see this image](https://imgur.com/a/FjxDdoI). If we had to find the max strength for node 7, we have 8 in the right sub tree

Comment: @Turtle I added more explanation, you are right, it is not as straightforward as it seems.

Comment: The idea is not wrong, but you don't actually need to implement your own data structure. You just need to be more clever only keeping current candidates for max strength.

Comment: @btilly yes I expected you can optimize further and use the fact that only some players matter, but I didn't see it and I knew it wouldn't lead to better time complexity. This keeping max or min of something in subtree can be useful in programming competitions, now I'm wondering if I always could have solved this with existing data structures back then and didn't need a custom AVL tree or just in this case.

Comment: It does not lead to a better big-O. But it leads to much better memory usage, and may lead to better constants. Particularly if the data structure stays small enough for cache. Plus a standard implementation is often more optimized than a hand-rolled replacement.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. In this case if the strengths are random, then you only keep `O(log(n))` entries in the data structure. Making the overall algorithm `O(n log(log(n)))`. Even if the strengths are not random, most of the time the data structure only does a lookup. Not an insert. Which reduces work.